# Updating geolocation data, gotten from an API through a cURL request, at a timed interval

Tags: php, ajax, geolocation, reload, php-curl

I am getting two values (Latitude, Longitude) through an API with a cURL request. My request looks like this:

```
function APIcall($method, $url, $data){
   $curl = curl_init();

   switch ($method){
      case "POST":
         curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
         if ($data)
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
         break;
      case "PUT":
         curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
         if ($data)
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);                              
         break;
      default:
         if ($data)
            $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
   }

   // OPTIONS:
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
      'APIKEY: example-key-here',
      'Content-Type: application/json',
   ));
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);

   // EXECUTE:
   $result = curl_exec($curl);
   if(!$result){die("Connection Failure");}
   curl_close($curl);
   return $result;
}

$get_data = APIcall('GET', 
'https://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites/25544', false);
$response = json_decode($get_data, true);
```

This call is situated in a separate file, `apicall.php`, in my root folder, which I can then effectively include where I need it. When I do, I use the values given to me in the `$response` variable, to echo out the value of both the Latitude and the Longitude, which is what I need:

```
echo $response['latitude'];
echo $response['longitude'];
```

I do this inside the script tag of my Leaflet.js map, to place a marker on it, at coordinates that the API provides:

```
mymap.setView([<?php echo $response['latitude']; ?>, <?php echo $response['longitude']; ?>], mymap.getZoom());  
marker.setLatLng([<?php echo $response['latitude']; ?>, <?php echo $response['longitude']; ?>]);
```

This is where my problem arises. My code above, only places the marker once, since the call is only made once (of course). How would I go about making more calls, at a timed interval, without having to reload my entire page?

Comment: use ajax to send request to backend script that then sends the request to the API is one option - fairly trivial to set that up with a timer

Comment: @RamRaider

I've tried something like this:

`function repeatAjax(){
$.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: 'apicall.php',
          success: function(resp) {
                    console.log("Success");

          },
          complete: function() {
                setTimeout(repeatAjax,5000); 
             }
        });
}`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the response headers when viewing the API endpoint you should notice they have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` which means you can make an HttpRequest directly from Javascript. You can do this with Ajax or Fetch - in the following I opted for `Fetch` as it is such a simple task with this API. There are, no doubt, similar options available directly from within jQuery but as I don't use it I cannot advise and when you look at the code you'll see no real need to use it either in this instance.
Because the API has been exposed to all origins there really is no need for the curl request!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Where is the ISS?</title>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
                /* api endpoint */
                let url='https://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites/25544';

                /* only for demo purposes - display output in this element */
                let out=document.querySelector('output');

                /* ultra simple callback to display data from API */
                const callback=function( r ){
                    out.innerText=Object.keys(r).map( ( k )=>{
                        return [ k, r[ k ] ].join( ':' )
                    }).join( String.fromCharCode( 10 ) )
                };

                /* Send a basic request to the api ( which returns JSON ) and process using callback */
                const fetchposition=function( url, callback ){
                    fetch( url ).then( r=>{ return r.json() } ).then( callback )
                };

                /* 
                    create a self-executing anonymous function with relevant 
                    parameters ~ this is in the John Resig style... 

                    This acts like `setInterval` or a self referencing `setTimeout`

                */
                (function( url, delay, callback ){
                    (function(){
                        setTimeout( arguments.callee, 1000 * delay );
                        fetchposition( url, callback );
                    })();
                })( url, 5, callback );             
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <output></output>
    </body>
</html>
```

Example data from one iteration:

```
name:iss
id:25544
latitude:34.995889522375
longitude:129.28250031522
altitude:422.37051205509
velocity:27577.33696572
visibility:eclipsed
footprint:4519.5039529858
timestamp:1572204467
daynum:2458784.3109606
solar_lat:-12.881716643173
solar_lon:244.02703108844
units:kilometers
```

From this one ought to easily modify the position of a marker on the map - or add new marker for each result...

---

Following comment regarding the `actual` api ~ in the top portion of PHP code send the API request using curl.

```
<?php
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_POST['query'] ) ){
        ob_clean();
        # send api request ~ using cURL, carrier pigeon or whatever
        exit( date( DATE_ATOM ) );
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Where is the ISS?</title>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{

                let out=document.querySelector('output');

                const ajaxcallback=function(r){
                    let div=document.createElement('div');
                        div.innerText=r;
                    out.appendChild( div ); 
                };
                const ajax=function(url,params,callback){
                    let xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                        xhr.onload=function(){
                            if( this.status==200 && this.readyState==4 )callback( this.response )
                        };
                        xhr.open( 'POST', url, true );
                        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                        xhr.send( params );
                };


                (function( url, delay, callback ){
                    (function(){
                        setTimeout( arguments.callee, 1000 * delay );
                        ajax( url, 'query=api', callback )
                    })();
                })( 'apicall.php', 5, ajaxcallback );               
            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <output></output>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort. And I am so sorry, but I should have specified. I would have done it like this, which would have been so much more simple, but the actual API that I am using is requiring me to pass a key in the URL, which I'm thinking is not such a good thing to have showing on the client-side in a production environment.

Sorry!